# How does a fat jar(spring boot) resolves class path if two file are of same name & package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, fatjar

I am building a spring boot fat jar using gradle script.

My fat jar has two libs among others say -

1. open-source.jar
2. open-source-modified.jar (In this I have few updates
   for files from earlier jar(#1) placed with same name and same
   package structure)

both the jar are present in gradle dependency section like

```
compile project('open-source-modified.jar')
compile 'path.open-source.jar.<version>'
```

How do I ensure while launching app (java -jar fatjar) that modified files in open-source-modified.jar gets loaded instead of those with same name & package in open-source.jar.

If it was not a fatjar we could have achieved same by constructing class path and placing modified.jar before the actual jar in class-path. But how do we achieve same with fatjar ?